# Invalid custom control height in android 7

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, controls

I need to implement my own custom renderer for picker control. Here is the code I've got so far:

Code behind:

```
public class DMGPicker : Picker
{
}
```

XAML

```
<localPicker:DMGPicker
    IsVisible="False"
    x:Name="Login_Language" />
```

And for android:

```
class DMGPickerCustomRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    public DMGPickerCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var castControl = (DMGPicker)e.NewElement;

            global::Android.Graphics.Color _color = global::Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(142, 142, 142);

            if (castControl.BackgroundColor != null)
            {
                _color = castControl.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid();
            }

            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(); 
            gd.SetStroke(3, global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#888888"));
            gd.SetCornerRadius(20);
            gd.SetColor(_color);
            Control.SetBackground(gd);
            Control.SetPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            Control.SetHeight(135);
            Control.SetHintTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(192, 192, 192));
        }
    }
}
```

My control is working fine, but I got problem in control height. On android oreo 8.1 its height is properly setted but in android 7 the control is too big. Here are screenshots

Android 7.0

[image: Android 7.0]

Android 8.1

[image: Android 8.1]

My control height is set to 135, but I assume that this problem has something incommon to screen resolution but I am not sure.

How can I force height for this control in all android versions (>=7.0)?

Comment: I have tested your code with emulator android 7.0, the control height is working fine.What device did you use?

Comment: I am using Samsung SM-J530F (Android 7.0 Api 24) for tests.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such device to test with it.I have tested with devices of android7.1, 6.0 and 8.1, and it all worked fine.